# Dúvida fwrite escrevendo no arquivo

Tags: php, javascript, html

Fala rapaziada, estou com um problema ao escrever em um arquivo usando o fwrite, eu consigo criar o arquivo normalmente porém na hora da escrita eu recebe o seguinte erro:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/i9pix942/public_html/i9/insert.php on line 36
```

Identifiquei que o problema está aqui dentro: fwrite($fp, "meu codigo")

Bom ali dentro eu tenho o seguinte código que preciso inserir dentro de cada arquivo criado. o código é esse:

```
fwrite($fp,"error_reporting(0);

ini_set('display_errors', FALSE);

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');  
$url = $_POST['pagina']

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);

//Define um User-agent
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:21.0) 
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

//Não retorna a resposta
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//Resposta
$data = curl_exec($ch);

if($data === false) {
echo 'Offline, detalhes do erro: ' . curl_error($ch);

} else {
$httpcode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

if ($httpcode >= 200 && $httpcode < 300) {
    echo 'Online';
    $status = 'Online';
} else {
    echo 'Site Offiline, Ou Página não encontrada. Erro HTTP: ' . $httpcode;
    $status = 'Offline';
}
}");
```

Bom voltando a LINHA 36 identifiquei que o erro é ocasionado por causa desse trecho abaixo que está no código:

```
$url = $_POST['pagina']
```

quando retiro essa parte acima consigo criar e gravar no arquivo normalmente.
alguém tem a solução ?

Comment: Falta o `;` nessa linha

Comment: Obrigado. Porém não fez diferença :/ o errk continua

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que isso ta acontecendo porque a string que tu está escrevendo no arquivo possui variáveis PHP que estão sendo interpretadas, tente substituir o '$' por outro caractere, ai depois quando tu for ler o arquivo tu substituí por '$' novamente.

No PHP tu pode concatenar de duas formas:

1) `"Nome: $nome"`

2) `"Nome:" . $nome`

Eu acho que é esse o problema, testei substituindo aqui e funcionou.